# Issue with Http Url Connection on android throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-asynctask

hello every one i am develop some application which make Http Connection with web service for check user name and password in the server.
when i make login that always throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected this exception and it's begin today , yestrday it's worked perfetcly
this my code to connection:

```
String username = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        String res="";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        String urllogin=getResources().getString(R.string.AppLogin);
        Content="phone_no="+URLEncoder.encode(username)+"&pass="+URLEncoder.encode(password);




        try{
            URL url=new URL(urllogin);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","close");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(Content.getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            OutputStream outputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(Content.getBytes());

            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                res = readStream(in);
            }
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
                res = readStream(in);
            }
```

and this the log or error when the exception is throw:

> 03-03 17:18:52.831 19012-19012/? E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mycompany.logintoapp, PID: 19012
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.URLConnection.checkNotConnected(URLConnection.java:463)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:877)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mycompany.logintoapp.MainActivity$ValidateLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:275)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mycompany.logintoapp.MainActivity$ValidateLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:225)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>   03-03 17:19:27.607 19012-20724/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>   03-03 17:19:27.619 19012-19012/? E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
>   03-03 17:19:27.628 19012-19012/? E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()

i am not understand what the problem yestdrday it's worked

**EDIT:**  the exception always throw in the this rows

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","close");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(Content.getBytes().length));
```

EDIT2: now i get always missing parameter when i make post but it's strange it's only in LG g3 5.0

Comment: I am having similar issues with my REST API server written in PHP but only with LG G3 and 5.0 as well... I will be sure to come back and write an update here if I can ever figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a FYI, you only need one if statement with an else. And simply specify which BufferedInputStream you need in each clause. Then do the setting after that. That way you're only checking for a response code once. Not sure if that's your problem here, but it would definitely help you, to try to ensure that you're only doing things once and once only. Makes it easier to debug the issue.

```
InputStream inputStream;
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
} else {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
}

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
res = readStream(in);
```

And ensure that you close all the streams, connection, etc, ready for next call.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2729) issue, this exception may be misleading and hiding a problem with a wrong URL. I suggest you verify that your remote server is running as expected and that the URL you are trying to connect to is, indeed, reachable.